# How long would it take to create a Windows 1.0 capable machine from complete scratch?

Tags: technological-development, computers, natural-resources

I've been thinking about this concept for a while and have not been able to figure out what could be a plausible answer. It seemed appropriate for my first question on this website.

Imagine an experiment where a group of approximately 20 humans are dropped off on a fairly small (~1000 km²) island that contains all necessary resources as they would appear in a natural environment. The group would then receive the challenge to **- starting completely from scratch -** build a fully functioning computer system capable of running at least Windows 1.0 with usable speed and then run it successfully as fast as possible. They would start off with no tools or resources. These are the rules and conditions that would be present:

- The group of humans would not need to worry about life supporting and maintaining issues such as food, clothing, weather conditions, natural disasters and hostile wildlife.
- The group would know **exactly** how to find and assemble **any** items involved in the process of creating the machine.
- The group consists of young and fit humans that would not experience any social issues within the group, and would not tire from consistent 12-hour working days.
- For convenience, we assume that the humans would not age or die during their participation in this experiment.
- The island contains any necessary resource in completely raw form. Materials like metals may be present in a higher-than-natural rate to ensure there is enough available for completing the challenge.

As I started thinking more about this concept, I began expecting the minimum time needed to achieve such a goal would probably be at least 5 years (*Edit: way above*). However I am probably underestimating the time it would take to obtain some of the necessary materials and build all of the advanced machinery that is used in assembling a fully functional computer system.

Could anyone suggest a reasonable time estimate for completing such an extreme task/challenge? What would be the biggest obstacles along the way?

*As this is my first time ever post on any StackExchange website, feel free to point out anything I should be doing differently.*

**Edit:** The challenge does not require building a version of the hardware that was actually being used to run and interact with the OS. As long as it gets the job done and the system is able to run at usable speeds, it could be built from any material and can be as big as it needs to be.

**Edit:** I have accepted Karl's answer as it portrays the most factual sequence of steps that would have to be taken in order for the team to achieve the necessary level of technology for building the machine.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45267/discussion-on-question-by-mano-gilissen-how-long-would-it-take-to-create-a-windo).

Comment: It would be entirely impossible - The island does not contain a copy of WIndows 1.0.

Comment: Why windows? Why not other OS? Why run any OS at all, instead of providing a machine with proper speed? We can measure memory or clock speed, you know. That's more reliable than checking whether some arbitrary OS will run at 'usable speed'.

Comment: I remember Windows 1.0 - claiming it _ran_ would be enough to make me laugh...

Comment: The *exact* knowledge is more of a giveaway than you think. No time required for planning! No need for prototypes or debugging! It's a superpower for engineer. Also, for fiction purposes, the group conflict is usually where the story is ..

Comment: If the humans live forever and never have to worry about survival, then really all you need is 1 person and [a bunch of rocks](https://xkcd.com/505/)

Comment: This is similar to one of my favorite existential questions (tailored to programmers) of all time. Roughly, "if you woke up alone in a forest, with nothing but an axe, and couldn't leave, how long would it take before you could send an e-mail?"

Comment: They should be able to get up and running pretty quickly if [crabs](http://hackaday.com/2012/09/28/making-logic-gates-out-of-crabs/) hang out on or around the island. And, if they've got mustard and tomato plants, they can even get the awesome [Windows 3.1 Hot Dog Stand theme](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-tribute-to-the-windows-31-hot-dog-stand-color-scheme/) by applying ketchup and mustard to the display crabs' shells.

Comment: Your question reminds me of _A Fire Upon the Deep_ by Vernor Vinge.

Comment: Check out the open source ecology project.  http://opensourceecology.org/about-overview/  These guys are trying to more or less solve this problem.  They're creating a list of 50 self replicating machines that can be used to rebuild modern society.

Comment: Do they have access to unlimited information?

Comment: what does "all necessary resources" mean? do they have to purify their own silicon and manufacture transistors and chips too?

Comment: I'd love to see a series of tubes, valves and water being used to flip leaves in order to turn "pixels" on and off. With infinite time and space you could do it with pebbles and a single hand :P

Comment: What are you claiming as "Windows 1.0 capable"?  Do you mean any x86-compatible CPU/architecture?  Or any architecture of comparable capabilities, even if it's not bitwise-compatible with x86 (and therefore unable to run a 'standard' instance of Windows 1.0)?  Are you aiming to exactly replicate the 8086 CPU architecture, or just approximate the performance of a circa 1985 8086 processor using any hypothetical architecture?

Comment: Windows is super-inefficient and requires the x86 architecture, so that might be not a good criteria.

Comment: Have you considered targeting Minix instead of Windows? -- It's much more suited to small computer systems. -- Someone [here](http://www.homebrewcpu.com/) built a Minix system out of 7400 series logic gates; it's a far stretch to go from that to manufacturing your own trasistors (but I mean you could build mechanical ones at the very least with reed switches, you still need a lot of industry for that, but at least your goal is possible -- might need more like 200 people though). -- Additionally it saves you the issue of building a display, you can just have them build a printer.

Comment: What if the answer is never because they can't repair or maintain the machinery as fast as it breaks. Even if you started them off at an almost there state, parts would get old faster than they could be replaced.

Comment: Let's get the "Primitive Technology" YouTube guy on this.

Comment: Hopefully, long enough for any primitive civilization to wipe out any of the mistaken developers and their ill-begotten plan. This question is like asking how long would it take to create a squared wheel from scratch.

Comment: [How I built a toaster from scratch](https://www.ted.com/talks/thomas_thwaites_how_i_built_a_toaster_from_scratch?language=en)

Comment: Are you aware that nothing useful ran on Windows 1.0? If people were going to do this, DOS 3.x would be an easier goal that's just as useful. Windows 3.0 was the first version that had *any* interesting software competitive with the DOS-based offerings of the time.

Comment: "No tools or resources". "The group would know exactly how to find and assemble any items involved in the process of creating the machine". So what you have here is a collection of people that know the entire curriculum of MIT by heart and do not need any kind of library to look things up. This would also mean that they know pretty much any physical constant you can think of... like the specific weights of different elements, orbital energies for the entire periodic table... and so on. This is entirely super-human... and not credible in the least.

Comment: By the time [The Myserious Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysterious_Island) was written, the world's collected knowledge in chemistry could fit in an encyclopedia. By then it was still credible that a group of people could keep sufficient knowledge in their heads to get to such a point where they could manufacture explosives. But to get to the point where you keep enough knowledge to build the components of a **computer** without any kind of infrastructure or library to help you... no, now you are in the realm of fantastic.

Comment: Not sure about MS Windows on a desert island, perhaps Palm OS would be more appropriate :P

Comment: Can your superhumans have kids? If so, are those kids superhumans? ... And I'd assume waive all objections against child labor. ... And can your "humans" be used _as_ supplies? ... ... Mega-creepy superhumans using their own bones to make tools? ... Or other tool uses of an immortal human?

Comment: Obviously 20 humans can become 40 in a few years

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This demands a full chemical industry developed. (Let's guess they can get at iron ore and coal somehow, and suitable material to make ovens, and you swiped a few axes, saws and shovels to start with. I cannot guess how long it might take to bootstrap those.)

Factories they need to build in chronological order.

- bricks, cement & construction supplies
- blast furnace
- machineshop
- steel production
- keep improving all previous production sites at all times
- glass factory
- base chemicals factory
- advanced machineshop (lathe, milling machine)
- polymer production
- copper&electrical cable production
- electrical power station (this needs a bit more thinking, might  need to be quite large)

Now you're in ~1890!

- advanced chemical factory
- aluminium factory
- semiconductor factory
- build first discrete electronics to help with all machining
- make your first integrated circuits
- build first computer with ICs, start programming
- develop CAD/CAM
- better computer, more highly integrated circuits
- develop programming environment for the final task

20 steps, let's say I forgot another five. You can probably do every task in a year or two, if you have 20 people for it and know exactly how, but you will run out of personnel very fast. All the earlier factories need to keep running while you build new ones, and you will need ever more people to keep maintaining and upgrading everything. The factories have to grow all the time to produce base material for all the new things you "invent". And you need ever more people to do the logistics&infrastructure and dig up the base materials. My guess would be 35 years and 20000 people, depending on how you get past the first steps. Perhaps half a million man-years. You have no chance with 20 people. ;-)

An open question would be how to power all this. Hydroelectric and coal could do the trick, but one would need an estimate of the amount of electrical and heating power needed. At some point solar power could come into play.

P.S.: Afterthought: The personnel requirements could perhaps be halved if you're really crazy and make this system to collapse with the target reached, i.e. no resources left, factories&infrastructure ruined of old age, etc.

P.P.S. I might add that I thought the people constructing everything still need to dimension everything, i.e. they know the general rules, formulas, physical constants, but don't have a readymade drawing for every machine. Giving them a huge stack of premade blueprints seemed like cheating to me, and impractical, because it'd be hard to know e.g. the exact mechanical properties of the stuff they produce, before actually doing it there. It'd be another 20 years of science&engineering today, to prepare plans for all contingencies. ;-)

P.P.P.S. Why all the factories? The 8086 is at the top of 20 years of integrated circuit development, and you need a lot of electronics already to build and test the machines that are used to actually make one 8086. The last steps can probably be more manufacture than factory, but I am sure you'll have to make dozens of the ICs each time before you get one that works (how would you know that your wafers' specs are sufficient, without building even more sophisticated analytics?).

P.P.P.P.S Why ICs? It is impossible to build a general purpose CISC out of discrete transistors and let it run at several MHz. A parallelised RISC supercomputer (like the CDC 6600 mentioned in the disc.), no problem, but we are talking binary compatible to the IBM PC. Further, millions of transistors for the SRAM would be a pain to build and assemble by hand, and the latencies in the long wiring (not talking about the capacitance and inductivity) would make it inoperational *in an 8086*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45322/discussion-on-answer-by-karl-how-long-would-it-take-to-create-a-windows-1-0-capa).

Comment: If your goal was just to build any computer that could run any OS -- you could build a very slow CPU out of discreet components, and run Minix -- [here](http://www.homebrewcpu.com/) a single person did it with 7400 series ICs (which typically just package logic gates which are mostly one or two discrete components per gate). -- However, you'd still need most of the industry that @Karl mentions just to build something compatible with this.

Comment: The other thing to consider is paper/pencil/ink production, etc. (I guess it goes in with other resources; but they're not going to build and design anything if they can't draw plans).

Comment: P.P.P.P.P.S: You don't need all those PS's.  Just integrate all of that new information into your answer naturally.  Otherwise, it reads like a newsfeed or forum.

Comment: 20 people with all construction supplies ill, in their lifetime, barely build all walls for all factories you ill need to build to produce this computer

Comment: @jean I believe this is exactly what I said above.

Comment: I like how you just handwaved mining, because that's what you're going to be doing for the first thousand years or so.

Comment: @Mazura That was in the original question.

Comment: I think I've played this game but I can't remember what it's called... I think eventually you got to build a rocket?

Comment: @CJDennis Civilisation?

Comment: +1 And you need to feed house and care for all your workers and build the tools needed to build the factories.  Your steps make sense (I think they would take a great deal longer 3-6 years per task even with trained people)

Comment: @CJDennis this reminded me of Factorio

Comment: I'm thinking you might have to invent and produce mechanical relays, and then vacuum tubes, and then transistors,  at least for prototypes, before you can think about integrated circuits. And since OP wanted just _one_ computer rather than millions, you might just use vacuum tubes and cover half the island with the computer. And core memory.

Comment: I gave you some rep, but from the perspective of an Electrical Engineer who used to design integrated circuits, the only correct answer is, "it can't be done under any circumstances given the OP's limitations."  Semiconductor fabrication alone takes 20-30 technology steps you haven't listed that require physics/materials/etc. knowledge that even I don't have.  There are no 20 people on the planet who could make it happen in their lifetimes... or ten lifetimes...  The mountain of knowledge to build what today wouldn't be a practical caluclator is that high.

Comment: @JBH OP said "they know what to do". And hey, an electrical engineer cannot fabricate ICs. You deliver the etching mask, let the chemists do the rest. It's no magic, and we speak of 1980, not 2010. And I said 20000 people will be necessary, not 20.

Comment: @Spencer OP said binary compatible and runing with useable speed. That is *impossible* with relays, vacuum tubes or even single transistors. 5 MHz is the number. Not 1 Hz, or 1 kHz, or 50 kHz.

Comment: @Karl, Fair enough, I mistakenly superimposed the OP's number over yours, but even with 20K people, it can't be done.  Period.  Not in their lifetimes.  The skills to build the computers, keep everybody alive, and manage the project exceed 20K people (and that's assuming 20K productive people).  And if you think Windows 1.0 capable computers can be built with an "etching mask" and a chemist, you know a whole lot less about electronic fabrication than I thought you did.  A lot less.

Comment: @JBH I said 20 chemists. ;-) No, I mean if you know what to do, and cut out the mass fabrication part, cut out any social, nutrition, health etc. issues (that's also in the original question), I see absolutely no problem. Grow small ingots, cut wafers, prepare for cutting into chips, a few etching and sputtering steps, cut chips, bonding by hand under a microscope, finito. There's three dozen different chips in an IBM PC (OK, five dozen if you include all necessary addons), and you build everything single purpose, so all interfacing is greatly simplified. And I left out monitor and disk drive.

Comment: Managing all that is another issue. Start everything at the perfect time, re-educating people when task are about to change, perfect logistics, no accidents, I know that's impossile

Comment: @Karl perhaps, but that was just my silly extension to my comment about having to go through those intermediate stages.

Comment: @Spencer Relays you need, and I have the advanced machineshop for that. Tubes you can leave out, they're not very useful if you have the knowledge of 2015, and have transistors made by the first stage of my semiconductor factory.

Comment: Where is an island going to get the electricity needed to do all this? Solar is a catch-22. Hydro is unlikely unless the island has extremely odd geology+hydrology. Nuclear? Heat engines - from burning what, and in what boiler? Even today, islands have oil shipped in to burn for electricity.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Good point! ;-) But a mountain with a high-up lake and enough rain should do it. At some point they can use solar power, and just don't give them cars and AC. Coal they need anyway to produce iron, so that's another source.

Comment: Can the 20 humans have babies?

Comment: "Hydroelectric and coal could do the trick." A splendid bit of understating the manpower requirements.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast If you have to build a dam for hydrolectric power, then you need a lot of people, right. I haven't given the amount of energy needed a lot of thought. Perhaps (or very likely, rather) it's quite significant. ;-)

Comment: Why can't this be done like a video game given the stipulations by OP? If we assume they don't age or die or tire why can't they just mass produce the needed resources then move on to the next stage and once they have enough of everything

Comment: @Himitsu_no_Yami Because you need tenthousands of items. If you do it all sequentially, you also have to *store* them. Twenty people would be barely enough to do the warehousing and building maintenance.

Comment: @Karl but, theoretically given enough time could it not be done? I'm not talking about it being _efficient_, just _technically_ possible even if it takes millions of years

Comment: @Himitsu_no_Yami If twenty people are absorbed alone by all the necessary warehousing, then twentyone could do it in millions of years. But I think thats not what the OP was after. ;)

Comment: @Karl thanks for that, I was mainly just curious if it was technically possible.

Answer (score 14):

There's only a few goals that are actual requirements and they have some low-hanging fruit:

- CPU, the only unique part that we want to move away from is mechanical switches. 
  Galena and a steel wire can make a natural contact junction as can rusty and non-rusty metal supposedly.
  One person has made some relatively simple [transistors](http://www.andaquartergetsyoucoffee.com/wp/?p=81), you could probably do something similar to that with the right chemical knowledge the materials used might even be simple to manufacture.
  I've heard current breaking down a dialectric can sometimes for junctions as well.
- Battery, Lead acid kind. You would need to build capacitors to smooth the power. Lead, like the rest of your metals, would be in raw form (or near enough) and sulfuric acid can be made with choice minerals and/or iron or platinum.
- Clock, you could make an inverter to provide a clock pulse or fashion a piece of quartz into a thin wafer (almost impossible but you only need to get lucky once).
- Display, a little harder but you could make a motor that signals you in binary. Possibly set up a grid of them for a screen.
- Input, crossed wires provide a keyboard input when they contact. You would build vertical and horizontal rows so they'te not touching and then pressing on a junction would complete the circuit.
- Memory, can be made as core memory from raw metals.

If you have raw materials instead of ores and a source of coal everything can be developed.
Wax, paper, and electroplating can be used to build a circuit board if you feel it's neecssary.
A solder iron could be made from a leather wrapped iron rod with solder being homemade (lead and tin alloy?).
You can cold work your way to the tools and material shapes you need after you cast your initial hammer head and anvil from iron.

If you spent about a week each on:

- collecting materials
- a kiln for your athracite coal to melt the iron, melt glass to make a case for the battery, etc.
- make a bellows and other small tools
- cast the anvil and hammer
- making blueprints/designs
- possibly one for papermaking
- possibly spending an additional few months for collecting special materials.

...and a few months assembling the created parts;

It still seems pretty reasonable to accomplish within a year given perfect knowledge, the right raw materials, and a decent set of able-bodies.

Comment: You get +1 for everything except the display. The result should run fast enough to be usable. I cannot imagine a display built from raw materials to be usable. I think you would need at least lightbulbs, color them in r/b/g and view them from a distance.

Comment: @Falco RGB is not necessary, for long time people where perfectly fine with monochrome displays.

Comment: Quartz is nice, because it is exact, but you can use other components like the transistor watch. Have a look at Bulova Accutron Spaceview

Comment: Problem is analytics. You might manufacture a lot of the necessary things, but you won't know how to get them to the necessary specifications, because you have no idea e.g. how pure your base materials are and what's in them. It's an ever growing zoo of additional methods, which is why i said, heck, lets do it properly, see my above answer. ;-)

Comment: @Falco technically you could build an LED pretty easily with Silicon Carbide but I figured rather than adding more material requirements a loop of copper was usable enough different levels of white would just spin the paddles faster. Also any LED at that tech level would be pretty fragile. Lightbulbs could be done with bamboo filaments but requires better glasswork than just a simple kiln (glass blowing pipe for one) and would probably be too dim to use in the sun.

Comment: @Karl I agree but I was going for shortest time period for a single prototype model. Also testing could be used. We already bin sort GPUs and CPUs and it's not that far of a jump to make qualitative electrical testing equipment. Then you just need to produce enough parts so that you have a compatible set of parts. It's still fragile but it's orders of magnitude faster than building all the manufacturing processes from scratch.

Comment: I think you underestimate everything, 192 kb RAM required for windows 1 requires 4.6 million transistors. You need to put them in close proximity to be able run your machine at a reasonable speed. Also non of the materials are ready you need to dig, refine and melt them. You don't have industrial heaters, you have to build them. The "home-made" transistors require tons of modern machinery that you would need to work on for a very long time. You won't need factory lines and stuff but building a decent electronics lab takes a lot of equipment (I know from experience).

Comment: @CemKalyoncu More like 10 million, actually. Usually SRAM uses 6 transistors per bit (FLIPFLOP plus 2 for read/write), plus a few more for addressing every WORD. The soldering iron alone warrants construction of an electrical power plant, making *miles* of wiring no less. ;-)

Comment: Well, I forgot about addressing, but I think you might make a ram with 3 transistors per bit. Never tried doing that to be honest. I am sure that 4 is enough.

Comment: @Karl I don't see why you couldn't heat up a soldering iron in a fire.

Comment: @immibis If you are prepared to solder ~50 million joints by hand (3-4 legs per transistor + plus a number of further connections for each, makes 50 man-years at 24/7 work, 1 min per joint), you can also heat the iron in a fire, right. You have no modern solder with flux in the bore, btw. ;-)

Comment: @CemKalyoncu The sheer amount of transistors/cores is scary, yes. Going a chemical route could get you there but the other methods are super bulky and fragile. Transistors are only needed for the CPU though core memory works as well. Making and weaving all the cores would take forever but you could pull it off easily in a year. You don't necessarily need "RAM" in the usual sense.

Comment: I thought about core memory at start but the size of that thing by the best estimate would be 7x7 meters. It will use more than 25 km of cable, 1.5 million iron cores. There will be 1024 + 1536 cables sticking on the sides. You will then need to address that thing. This means you need a mapping table from 16 bits to 2560 cables. This thing will drain a lot of electricity. I am not sure if it can be built stably.

Comment: @Black You need 200 kbyte of uniformly addressable RAM, with clock speed and latencies at least close to what IBM sold in the late 70ies. The computer you contemplate would get you in front of a court for boring users to death, running MS Windows. ;-)

Comment: You both are right of course in that it would be absurd. Do able but absurd. There would be many wires sticking out and it would have latency that would make you cry but it would run. AFAIK core memory doesn't waste wattage as bad as you're thinking @CemKalyoncu, It can work on a single bit instead of the whole net.

Comment: The biggest downfall to catapulting to this computer right out of the gate is there's no infrastructure so a faster computer than the initial one, really isn't possible. Wanting more computers is also hard.

Comment: Honestly, it might be easier to use a magnetic medium to augment a smaller memory array (i.e. the hardware equivalent of a swap file). -- I'm thinking something similar to how a turing machine works. -- Actually it need not even be magnetic, but that would be faster than mechanical memory. -- And you'd have to build the logic into your memory controller (so as to "emulate" the right amount of memory), and it would add a lot of latency to the end product, but at least it would be buildable.

Comment: As for the display -- your colonists have to figure out paper and ink anyway (they're not going to finish designing this stuff without it), why not just use a printer? -- All of the early computer systems just interfaced directly with printers / and the earliest computer displays could only display like 40x4 characters on an LCD, etc.  (Obviously that won't work for Windows, but that's not a realistic goal IMO.)

Answer (score 13):

I am assuming they have all the knowledge necessary readily accessible, in form of books or a magic tablet which does not run out of battery.

Your estimate is very low. It would take very very long time to get to a point to generate electricity. You need electronic machinery to build smaller electronics. Hell, even building a solder iron would take a very long time. Imagine melting and casting copper into stone to create wires. Also you might need to dig oil to make plastics, as some cables will definitely require insulation. Before you get to any of this, you will need tools to dig the ground. You will probably have to work with stone tools until you get to a point to make iron tools.

To sum up, you will go through whole of industrial revolution and then some, where thousands of engineers were working during that period to advance the field. I am not including scientists as your people have the knowledge. All in all, I would guess it would take around 50 years, probably more.

Comment: 5 to 10 years was needed to master making bronze tools, and these was needed to make iron (dig ore, make smelters). Next 5 to 10 to make decent ironwork. Then, to steel! 50 years is pretty low estimate, given that they need some time before bronze, and a lot after steel. On the other hand, you can skip plastics entirely (rubber and oiled paper can do the job pretty well).

Comment: I don't think you would need steel. Rubber could work though. Oiled paper is not the best idea, it would require lots of infrastructure to make paper of sufficient quality.

Comment: It would be hard to prepare Czochralski silicon without steel tools - and that's the simplest method of getting silicon suitable for integrated circuits in large enough quantity.

Comment: Well you won't need large quantity, I initially thought you could get away without silicon, but it seems windows 1 needs a whooping 192 kb of memory. On the other hand, if you know how to do it, it won't be too hard to make steel.

Comment: 50 years to make an electronic computer from a scratch? Come on, get real. Talk in centuries!

Comment: It took centuries first time, but there was time to research, fight wars and stuff. These people have the knowledge and 12 hours per day. I would say 50 is not far fetched.

Comment: I was told long ago that if you wiped out all stored human knowledge, the same generation would make it back to the internal combustion engine by only what is carried in our heads, and the next would be in position to attempt the electric motor. And that's w/o the magical ability to avoid human need. From there we can only guess.

Comment: I was really surprised the conclusion of this paragraph was 50 years. Sounds like you were arguing for centuries or millenia.

Comment: @joshua Electric motor is actually extremely simple. And it also produces energy when put in a turbine or something similar. I'd say it's actually easier to produce and use electrical power than internal combustion engines. As long as you know some background basics.

Comment: Electric motors are easy if you have thin wires and patience.

Comment: @darthzejdr: The problem isn't the motor; it's the technology and infrastructure to make electricity a viable energy transmission source. Internal Combustion Engine is simply more effective during bootstrap.

Comment: "It would take very very long time to get to a point to generate electricity" - I find this hard to believe.  To produce electricity all you need are 1) permanent magnets, 2) copper wire, 3) an axle, and 4) something to make the axle spin (water, wind, fire, etc.).  And a bit of math if you want to fine-tune things to produce output within a desired specification.  It may take awhile to reach something approximating a modern power-station, but small-scale electricity generation should be _almost easy_.

Comment: To dig deep enough to find permanent magnets, copper, and iron, you need tools, not just shovel and a pickax, you need to sustain the weight of the mine. You need furnace to melt iron. This is the easy part. To make copper wire you need have close to perfect molds. You also need to insulate those wires. Do you know the length of copper wire on a generator?

Comment: The OP offers "Materials like metals may be present in a higher-than-natural rate to ensure there is enough available for completing the challenge" as a given.  I think that means you can do without any substantial/large-scale mining operations.  Wire is made by stretching the metal out, so not sure why you'd need perfect molds?  And insulation sounds like an optional safety-feature?  Even if it's not, surely they can find some non-conductive material to coat their wires with?

Comment: Motors and generators are made out of very thin wires that are insulated wrapped around a magnet. Without insulation they will short. Wire making machines require electricity, motors, and heaters, first time around I thought you probably would mold the wire. But it seems it is easier than that, there seems to be different techniques regarding making wires. Generators get hot, rubber as we talked before won't help at all. Winding wires are coated with polymers not simple plastics.

Comment: Couldn't you use ceramics for insulation? you don't need flexibility

Comment: @aroth Except you don't have permanent magnets which are all you need to make electricity. You need electricity to make them. And suddenly an easy problem becomes complicated.

Comment: @Peter: Generators tend to use electromagnets, as normal "permanent" magnets a) don't produce sufficient flux, b) become weaker over time. All you really need is an iron core of sufficient size and purity, and heavy duty wiring. You'd probably need to use electrochemical reactions, i.e., a battery, to produce your initial cables, and start your generator (substitute vegetable oil for diesel), then use that as an energy source when making a larger thermal power plant. Regarding insulation, they used to use cotton cloth as insulation in the 50s.

Comment: You need to wind those wires thus should be flexible. cotton is not a good alternative but could work. Then again, you will need to cultivate cotton.

Answer (score 11):

Rather than reinventing most of industrial civilization from scratch, I think your engineers will be better off thinking 'big' and developing a mechanically actuated machine from simple materials, like wood and fibers.  I'll continue the trend of your generous assumptions and assume that your operators will operate the system perfectly, so you don't break any of the components.  I'll also assume they carve and position everything perfectly so that you don't have to worry about the inevitable wear issues with moving/sliding wood parts.

It will be painfully slow to harvest all those resources with stone age technology, but still quite a bit faster than reinventing all of mining and metallurgy, let alone everything you need to manufacture semiconductor technology.

I'm imagining a huge machine with:

- A 'monitor' composed of patches of mechanically rotated dark/pale plant leaves as 'pixels'.  You'd want to miniaturize this at least somewhat to make it usable, so this would probably be one of the most delicate parts of the mechanism.  You'll probably also want to settle for a relatively low resolution.  I'm imagining a vast array of sliding horizontal straight poles that adapt to vertical poles to rotate their corresponding pixels.  You'd probably need to lay them out overlapping in 3 dimensions to get enough density.
- Mechanical switches that transform translation of a pole into either coupling or decoupling two other poles (so they 'transmit' only when the 'base' pole is actuated.)  Basically you have a logic system composed of latching relays, with signals actuated by translation (and likely adapted/routed via rotation in various places.)
- Timing and power is supplied by people pedaling wooden wheels, with clever mechanical governance to transform into a clock cycle.  This is where I doubt whether 20 people could supply enough power/speed to run 'fast enough' for your purposes.  If it's not enough to run it 'live', you could store power using lifted weights or flywheels, so you operate the pedals for, say, a day, then you get a few minutes of runtime.  Scale up as desired.
- For memory bits, you can leverage potential energy from gravity to store (literally lifted) bit states, with a read and refresh logic.

This is still a ridiculously massive engineering project, even if it is 'low-tech' from materials standpoint.  Still, the basic components are all there to execute logical circuits and thereby build a fairly powerful computer.  It's hard to estimate the labor involved, but I'd say you're probably still looking at a decade or more, just due to the sheer number of elements required.  And that's assuming everything goes perfectly, with no mistakes made in manufacturing all these ideal parts by hand with stone tools.

Comment: actually not bad, people in minecraft did processors

Comment: Clever, but such a device would not be fast enough to usefully run a Windows 1.0 type operating system, which requires an execution capacity in the low millions of instructions per second (the Intel 80486 of the era averaged 40 million instructions per second). By contrast, Alan Turning's codebreaker, which was state-of-the-art in the 1940s, managed 300 instructions per second. Your mechanical wood-and-leaf machine, properly greased with animal fat, would peak in the tens of instructions per second, before breaking.

Comment: @MolbOrg It's a common excercise in any game that allows that, yes (remember Dwarf Fortress catputers? And waterputers? And a dozen of other designs? :P). But it usually hinges on something quite unrealistic - ignoring friction, energy etc. A redstone-like approach would be a lot closer to reality than a mechanical computer - but even then, the computer would be way too slow, with way too little memory to come close to running Windows 1.0.

Comment: @Luaan people do some cpu implementations on relays, may be not the best example but a [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MM4IUxXiArY). Work frequencies are few hertz, there are ways to get higher efficient speed(FPGA, GPU style). Someone mention https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDC_6600 in comments that is good enough if speed is concern. Overall first mass produced processor where 5000-6000 transistors, no so much.

Comment: @MolbOrg FPGA is already a highly integrated circuit - that makes a lot of difference. The switching speed is very high, and the distances between the transistors are very short. The only reason FPGA's can't rival "normal" CPUs in raw processing power is that their multi-purpose gates are (slightly) more complex than most of those in a common CPU. And Windows 1.0 is already a significant resource drain on a CPU made from TTL ICs (like one I've made), that only becomes worse when you replace TTLs with discrete transistors. The OP asks for Windows, not useful computation.

Comment: @Luaan *The only reason FPGA's can't rival "normal" CPUs in raw processing power* - they can and they do, ask any bitcoin miner. I meant conveyor belt of data. I meant some principles, which could be used to improve speed a little. Kinda hyper-threading on relays - all that kinda tricks we learned last 10y. Do not meant to mimic them exactly, and yes speed will be still a problem, compared to first processors. Just felt it was worth to notice,

Comment: @MolbOrg They couldn't rival a chip specifically designed for bitcoin mining - that's my point. FPGA's are great in their flexibility, which allows you to reconfigure them to be more *specific* than general purpose CPUs, or just make a relatively cheap "chip". The problem with hyper-threading and out-of-order execution etc. is that it's incredibly complex. It's fine to make a homebrew CPU with 5000 transistors, especially if you have at least basic ICs for things like "16-bit AND"; making a multi-core, hyper-threaded, OOE CPU with three levels of cache... a lot more complex.

Comment: @Luaan complexity is not a problem with OP's premise, only physical implementations and how much in kg's. Even I probably understand you point, clearly I failed to express my. Complexity is not issue, we might have ASIC style windows here, there is not task to replicate past development, and it opens some possibilities, they did't implemented not because they had no possibilities, but because of knowledge and marketing issues, both of those are not issues in OP's setting. If they need 100t of gold for task, they have, nuclear reactor no problem. Power of labor is bottleneck, not finances.

Comment: @MarkMicallef The 80486 CPU is not from the Windows 1.0 era. The 80486 became available in 1989, when Windows was at version 2.1. When Windows 1.0 was released in early 1985, Intel was on the 80286, running at around 8MHz.

Answer (score 10):

See [the links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Ciarcia) to building the “MPX-16” from scratch in 1983. This is sourcing the integrated circuits that were available when such machines were built by IBM.  You can see the overall complexity and scale of the design.

Now you just need to build a silicon wafer “fab” and create the perfect crystal wafers… well, even if you supposed chipmaking could be scaled down to a home darkroom kind of thing, the industry needed to produce wafers is well beyond you little band.

That will be true even for the roughest semiconductor transisters; e.g. the stuff the Apollo mission used.

Any earlier technology would not be capable of running fast enough (as specified).  Oh, and you want a CRT display to go with that?  Again, we need *industries*, not a small party of individuals.

Comment: Fun fact: we've currently lost the industry required to create new CRTs.  We know how to make them (for now, provided copyright doesn't obliterate some of the finer important details over time before final release into the public domain) but have no actual way to make anything much more advanced than a simple deflected beam monochrome display.  Even the phosphors are hard to get now, so image persistence / tube lifetime would be way off a good NOS tube.  The mountain of continuous industry required to just maintain our way of life is truly and terrifyingly staggering.

Comment: @madscientist159 I believe you but I'm curious to read more. Do you have any links about this?

Comment: For example, what about https://www.thomaselectronics.com/manufacturers/ ?

Comment: @fabspro I'm basically using apex CRTs like Trinitron as a canary here -- simpler CRTs may still be made, for now, but they will also stop production over time. CRT manufacture is already stepping backward in terms of complexity, and that will only accelerate. There are a few sources for this, but here's just one Google picked up http://venturebeat.com/2017/03/03/what-the-death-of-the-crt-display-technology-means-for-classic-arcade-machines/  "When the last major manufacturer stopped making CRTs, they sold ... to a Chinese company that couldn’t properly reproduce the winding procedure"

Comment: @madscientist159 Trinitron is kinda an exception, but you're certainly right that the future is not good for the CRT. :(

Comment: @fabspro Trinitron was also arguably, in terms of visual quality, the best CRT ever created.  I used quite a few different models back in the day (as I suspect you have as well, from your comments :)) and the quality difference was very obvious.  Even losing that apex manufacturing bodes poorly.

Answer (score 7):

This answer focuses on the computer goal, rather than the process to create the computer.

"As long as it gets the job done and the system is able to run at usable speeds, it could be built from any material and can be as big as it needs to be."

If you drop the requirement for "usable speed" then a simulation could be done using anything as memory markers.  Lay out a massive grid on the ground to represent memory, and fill it with some kind of markers that mean 1 or 0, or use scratches in the soil.

Upshot: No industry required beyond feeding and housing and caring for the workers.

Downside: Time - the computer will run at hundreds-to-millions of seconds per cycle, rather than millions of cycles per second.

Answer (score 6):

If they know what to do then probably two major problems comes in to mind

Transporting resources and gathering them is one problem

Second problem is low number of those peoples.

first is a problem because island is actually big, and if resources are scattered, it means pretty big distances. Getting-mining resources even is they are rich in quantities is not an easy task, and it gets not easier over time as demands will probably grow. Just moving 1 tonne at distance 10km with wheels etc without roads might occupy them all for day or more. But you have dig that tonne first, and it is not pure so it means to get 1 tonne of product they have haul more then 1 tonne of ore.
So where resources are, in with form they are, surface of that island, distances might be bottleneck factors.
Moving those resources across production complex is also a problem, gravity is a ... do not know the word, heavy might be.

As for second problem, number of peoples, they have not just replicate and fast-forward stone-steam-electricity as it was done and scale it for 20 people, but it have to be done in the way specially designed for those number of peoples, needs should never exceed 20 peoples doing something at the time.
With no automation - at steam era, you have to have peoples almost for everything, they should work, watch, control, oil things, check that water gets in the boiler (not all systems which are used for that are reliable, and they tended to break or get our of regime their work) - so basically for moderate size steam machine it needs 2 people - one feed it, one watch it will not blow up and that it still rotates(kinda).

This get us to energy problem - how much energy can produce 20 humans with tools. At any point of that path stone-steam-electricity - there will be upper limit how much energy they might produce, in therms of power.

So whole process should not exceed their power production capabilities, their controlling capabilities. Glass making may need 24/7/365 watch - so 2 people out of whole process, and if there will be more then 9 such process at a time - they will run out of peoples.

And candidates for multiple points are chemical processes, there is a lot of chemistry involved in producing chips, not only for used chemistry in production, but used to produce that chemicals which are produced.
Purity of chemicals might depend on bulk production, just because in big jar impurities form jar itself are less percentage then in small volume production. Some chemicals store not so well because of instability of them, impurity will grow over time - so it might be impossible to produce all needed stuff and make check-marks - or you produce 10 of them at once in short time or you produce none of them - just kinda exaduration, but who knows.

Making the process which leads to end result for those 20 peoples is more challenging then just replication of what we have done. I'm very interested in looking at their model just for brief moment, very exciting.

Sorry, but I'm not ready to estimate time, as have almost no glue what to do father then steam era. And not sure do they need 20m high refining columns for chemicals - if case they need to produce just one piece of that equipment which runs linux.

Steam era, they probably might achieve it pretty fast, less then a year, if they have no problems to know what to do and skills needed to do that.
For real situation with people (not robots) I would say no way for 5y, but robot style people, may be may be, I consider it as possible. But this number is as good for me as 10y or 15y or 2y.
50y? do not think so, or they can do it in less time, or they just can't.

Comment: It's a small island why would transporting resources be a problem?

Comment: Well, a watermill would be a lot better option for power than a steam boiler, if they have that option (I'm not sure if there's a chance for a useful river on a 10 are island; could it ever be rainy enough? :D). Even wind might be feasible, depending on local conditions. A stirling engine would require very little maintenance, and isn't too hard to build, though the energy output is rather low.

Comment: @NuWin would not say it is small it is something like 33x33km square or 35km diameter round island - it is like big city, but without roads. Building roads is power intensive task, which is not very useful if you do not transport goods in bulk, and is problem for lot of countries even today, with more then excess of peoples. Something like that are reasons to notice it as a problem.

Comment: @Luaan because of those options and uncertainties energy production is out of scope of my answer, at least at the moment. Steam engine is more example, which was used for manufacturing tasks, and we can find some data about that and know problems using them at production. Good river would be definitely good help, wind not so much(unreliable, not lot of power for the work, nice needs wood and good to go), good Stirling is hard to build complexity is on combustion level of engines, toys are bad examples, take look at few kW stirlings. I would rather go with turbines - but it is my preference.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, let's look at the requirements for Windows 1, it is an 8 bit computer with 385k RAM memory.

So, if you have space, it is possible. DIY computers are really not something difficult to make.

[image: Image from http://hackaday.com/2012/04/20/building-a-computer-with-discrete-transistors/]

Displayed here is a board with transistors, that together makes a 4 bit computing processor.

In simplified terms, this is basically it, the challenge is to make $2^3$ times more efficient and smaller the oscillator (crystal frequency) can be increased and so small it fits in inside the area of a coin. But that wasn't one of the requirements.

Now the problem is, to make it out of something that looks like this:

[image: replica of first working transistor.]

It would take a lot of space.

A fast google of DIY RAM Memory shows that something similar could be made, fairly easy, where the true challenge is to make it small and modular. But given the means to extract the resources the area to build it, (I mean Boeing production size buildings), it could be done.

Regarding the running speed, I'm afraid I'm not experienced enough in that area, to know what speed it would run but it would largely be controlled by the switching capabilities of the transistor but I could not find the datasheet of the "first transistor" but a general purpose transistor has a switching capability of about 300 MHz.

Comment: RAM is actually quite a big deal. The problem isn't making a bit of memory (SRAM is very simple, really). The problem is making a *lot* of memory - even Windows 1.0 required almost 200 kiB of memory. That's huge.

Comment: Yes, i did write that it would take a lot of space didn't i?

Comment: The problem is that big size means slow operation. Making a CPU fast enough for Windows 1.0 isn't too big of a deal, even from simple-to-make TTL chips; it might even be doable with discrete components. However, making *memory* fast enough for Windows 1.0 *is* a problem - exactly because of the size required. Note how the silicon area of any modernish computer is dominated by memory (DRAM and SRAM). The propagation of electricity is too slow to maintain the speed you need.

Comment: A computer in 1985 runs at about 5-8 Mhz, with the transistors switching capability of 300 MHz you got a 150% overhead on that account, i don't really thing that would be the bottle neck.

Comment: First, you need to take into account how many transistors are in a series in any given operation - as a very rough estimate, you can only afford logic that uses less than sixty transistors in a series per operation to keep the 5 MHz, and that's already ignoring the paths *between* the transistors. Second, don't forget latency. Even if your memory could operate at 300 MHz, it doesn't help much if it takes 20 CPU ops to get data to the CPU. Ignoring the transistors, if your memory is 10 meters far from the CPU, you're already pushing the limits at 10 MHz.

Comment: can confirm @Magic-Mouse , as I dug history, saw statements that memory at first was faster then cpus (not totally strong confirmation but)

Comment: @Luaan twisted pairs working at higher distances then 10m with frequencies you mention.

Comment: @Molborg Yes, memory was faster than CPUs for a time (this was still true at the time of the Windows 1.0). That's why I'm noting that in Magic Mouse' computer, it would already be the other way around. And I wasn't talking about frequency on the cable, but on the CPU - note how I'm talking about latency in the communication. If the CPU doesn't have out-of-order processing, it *must* wait on memory on each memory operation, which puts a limit on how fast the memory must be not to impede the CPU. Not a big deal for calculation, very much a big deal for Windows.

Comment: "you're already pushing the limits at 10 MHz" - ofcause i am. we are talking about hand crafted components versus. high accuracy IC-components. I also just rated it plausible within 5 years, not possible.

Comment: @Luaan make L1 L2 cache, program it wise to minimize border crossing, But yes I missed the point initially.

Comment: No, you're missing my point. Just the electricity lag would be enough to discount anything above ~10 MHz (synchronous, of course - there's a lot more you can do with asynchronous, but that makes the whole system much more complicated). That's before it gets to the transistors, and assuming optimal addressing (in practice, you would need much more than just the 10 meters of wiring to address anything in the huge memory core). And how much memory could you fit in a cube of 10m? If it takes a cubic cm (generous) to store one bit, you get about 1 MiB - ignoring all the addressing circuits etc.

Comment: @MolbOrg Yup, but that's very complex. You need at least some measure of out-of-order execution (very complex), some cache allocation strategy, cache transparency etc. The 8086 had no on-chip cache, and it was already pushing the limits of the technology Intel had at the time. Suddenly, your 5000 transistors doubled, even when not counting the transistors you need for the onboard cache in the first place. And that might be an optimistic estimate :D

Comment: @Luaan you are confusing old components with making something "new from scratch" with primitive tools, we have advanced computers who can calculate and design the system, beforehand. "The group would know exactly how to find and assemble any items involved in the process of creating the machine." So the problem here is finding components in nature and assemble it, it says nowhere that they could not have CAD and or calculated strategy with them.

Comment: I don't mean just the complexity of design. It takes a *lot* of transistors to get that functionality. Sure, part of the reason this wasn't used in the past was that it a) wasn't cost effective, b) was hard to design. But cost-effective applies in our scenario as well - there's a difference between making a homebrew CPU with 5000 transistors, and 5 *million* transistors. We can't make a better 8086 today - all the improvements since (beyond making the transistors smaller and faster - not applicable in our scenario) were huge shifts in the whole design of the CPU.

Comment: Well basically it ends up being the production force of 20 people making makeshift transistors for 12 hours a day

Comment: The 8086 is a 16 bit computer, as is the 8088, which is an 8086 limping along with an 8 bit memory bus. And forget 5 MHz, you'll be lucky if you can get to 100 kHz with all the capacitance and inductivity in the miles of wiring you'll need. 30000 transistors for the 8086, plus 6.4 million more for 200*8 kbit of SRAM (4 transistors for each bit).

Answer (score 3):

Putting things together is information.  The arrangement of metal that distinguishes a pile of coal and rusted iron from tempered steel is information.

The way we usually do this is through crude processes that generate gradients that rearrange the locations of the atoms in a favorable way, and we iteratively move towards the arrangement of matter we want.

This involves the application of energy to generate a entropic gradient of the right shape, which is the only way we know how to mass re-arrange atoms into a new form.

But it is just information.  Some energy needs to be added to get some states from others, but the net energy difference after processing tends to be far far less than the energy used -- most of the energy is leaked off as heat, not captured.

This leaked heat is entropy -- loose information.  The ordered energy we use to induce the changes stuffs some of the information into the new structure, and the vast majority leaks off as heat.

If all the humans know is our current crude methods of infusing stuff with the structure we want, then they'd basically have to reinvent industrial civilization.  Time would be measured in generations not years, as they would have to breed a population sufficient to manage the industrial civilization needed.

If they instead had *all of the information they need to make it efficiently*, and the ability to *exactly* use that information, they could literally walk around and hit things perfectly with hammers and cause them to reassemble into the shape they need.

Remember, all that is required to uncrack an egg that fell off a table is the exact right set of taps, impacts and sounds.  It is the lack of information, and the difficulty in doing the actions exactly (low energy, extreme precision) that makes this impossible.  The easiest way for a human to uncrack an egg is to feed the cracked egg to a hen, or compost it and feed the food you grow to the hen.

This level of knowledge and precision in action is far beyond what any human could do, but you did say the had **exact** knowledge on how to do it.  And mere mortals have social issues.  Clearly you are not talking about mere mortals, as they have no social issues.

---

So if each woman produce 6 children per generation, 3 of which are women, and the population is half men, after 10 generations you have ~120,000 people.  After 20 generations you have ~7 billion people.  I'd expect it to be somewhere in that interval without perfect information.

With **perfect** information, they walk around tapping things and those things reform into the exact ingredients they need.  They touch them together, tap them, and they bond together.  Their actions look more like magic than industry.

Comment: Mike Resnick "Oracle" - probably not the level of knowledge OP is talking about. Any way It takes time and do not negate laws of physics.

Comment: An interesting take on the problem! I suspect our (super-intelligent) humans would be intensely frustrated: They would know exactly what "taps" are needed in what sequence to build their device, but lack the sensory precision to place and direct those taps as needed, and they would lack the muscular precision to execute the necessary taps.  TL;DR perfect information is useless without the ability of perfect execution.

Comment: @Spike0xff Well, you tap.  And it doesn't work.  So you tap somewhere else.  With perfect information, you can find the tap that would most move the system towards the state you want given the accuracy of your tapping tool (the first step, of course, would be building a more accurate tapping tool).  The humans spend decades making seemingly useless devices, then start tapping things with them, and get a computer a year later.  :)

Answer (score 3):

They can do it in seconds.

"The group would know exactly how to find and assemble any items involved in the process of creating the machine."

If their brain is programmed with what ever knowledge they need for making anything. Just make 1 of the 20 people the computer. The only real thing required will be a language to interact with the "computer" so that any one of the 19 other people using it can figure out what is happening, and since they already know everything they need to do, they can just do it. The "computer" can encode any information it wants into sound and the 19 people can decode the sound in their head into windows 1.0 UI. A person should be able to process any high level UI level command within a reasonable time with training, and since these people know everything they need, they should be able to do it.

If above is not valid because they didn't create the machine. Then it would take 9 months for 2 of them to biologically create a new machine and then a couple years of training to get the machine programmed correctly.

Comment: If the case had been that people had to make a "computing machine" I would disagree, but the question just asks for a "computer system"; ergo this is the best answer.  Back in the day we even used to have jobs for people whose titles was "computer", they were responsible for calculating things.

Comment: I think you underestimated the time needed to create a new machine. With only a couple of years of programming, the system would be very high maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, let me give you the perspective of an Electrical Engineer who once designed integrated circuits and knows a bit about the history of computing.

Given the limitations proposed by the OP, it is ***IMPOSSIBLE*** to develop the technology necessary to build a computer running Windows 1.0.  There ***IS NO LENGTH OF TIME*** that will change that.  The mountain of technology is so large, the developmental basics so great, and the knowledge so specialized at thousands of points along the developmental path, that it's impossible.

*Sorry*

(I upvoted Karl's answer because it was well thought out, even though he's not familiar with some of the core technolgies... but as much as I liked the answer, this one needed to be provided.)

Answer (score 1):

Any piece of technology that is newly developed is, at its time, the pinnacle, or the sum of *everything* and *everybody* that went on before, within the "light cone" of the involved people or logistic processes.

In the stone age, presumably, this kind of "light cone" was relatively slim - individual tribes probably re-invented the same technology (sharp stones fixed to a stick) relatively independently from first principles. Over time, travelers or raiders brought ideas into circulation; culture developed. By the time of, say, the old Greeks (Alexander), Chinese, the Roman Empire etc., the light cone was - for the most advanced bits and pieces of their time - probably their core city state (and then shone outwards towards the "barbaric" regions they occupied).

Fast forward today: the "light cone" that goes into our current products (computers, etc. - even in the 1980's) is arguably *incredibly* large. It is so large that we are incapable of, for example, determining the true economic footprint of most of our wares - we are not even able to measure/document the logistic and product chains going into T-Shirts, never mind electronics.

Sure, a lot of our complexity comes from the fact that we not only produce one piece of everything, but do mass production; so on the face of it it may seem you can shave a lot off if you don't need that. But this argument does not work for your question. You *need* mass production for a lot of what you are doing - for example even your single Windows 1 capable machine needs lots and lots of repeated pieces (resistors, whatever). So even for a component only one or steps removed from your end product you already need to figure out the prerequisites to mass manufacture stuff. Surely not on the scale we have on Earth.

You might argue that the knowledge of the goal and all the principles along the way would change the time line significantly; and in the ideal world (nothing gets forgotten etc.) it probably would. Still, as long as you have humans in the loop, you still need a *lot* of those, since every one is simply incapable of cramming arbitrarily much applied knowledge into their head.

Finally, it is not like our technology was created in a completely planned fashion - we have demonstrated that this goes horribly wrong. The fact that we have (many) millions of people working in science and industry also enabled the evolution-like approach we have today - we are trying and failing a lot, and this is inherently important in the system. This kind of trial and error is a *feature*, not a bug. You'd arguably need to replicate it on your island - i.e., for non-trivial topics, you'd need multiple teams trying to achieve the same goal at the same time.

And then we get to the crux: all those people need to be born, grow up, be educated, fed, clothed... and voila, there's our whole Earth economy as a non-optional pre-requisite.

So, as you are limiting your time scale to well within a single generation, it's not possible for systemic reasons (not just scale).