How much technological progress could a group of modern people make in a century?
[I have edited the question to include more details]
A group of let's say, 2500 people wake up from suspended animation on a world terraformed beforehand to be very similar to Earth. These people, while having fuzzy memory at first, slowly recover it, and are able to remember everything about modern life - but are unable, due to horrible software mistakes - to access certain types of equipment and digital archives that had been prepared for them to restart settlement.
While they are not able to access large machinery in storage, weapons, and other high level technologies, they do have access to a finite stock pile of food and medicine rations [let's say enough to last them all a year at a stretch.]
Thus, while they have many specialists in many fields, preselected for their expertise, they are on their own. While there area higher level specialists among them, there are specialists trained in basic technology/wilderness survival in the event that a situation like this has occurred. All of the individuals chosen to be put into suspended animation are working age adults. Further detail, the people are woken up in waves, starting with the wilderness survival experienced people first, as they were chosen to wake up first to scout out their surroundings and make sure everything is safe.
Assuming that they are in a temperate climate, how much technological progress could one expect them to make in a century? Side question, seeing as they need a lot of workers to rebuild civilization, how much could we expect their population to increase, excluding any major disasters?

Tough to say if they even survive. Where on Earth - desert, clay-wield in a temperate zone, steppes etc.?

How much training have they had for scenarios where they would have to survive without the expected equipment? Since it sounds like there was planning for this, one could expect some preparation/training for worst-case-scenarios. The amount of survivalist knowledge could make a big difference.

Do they have basic equipment?  Clothes, hand tools, etcetera?  If not, I would expect them to die in the first winter, or earlier still if they have no seed crops.  I would expect massive technological regression, rather than progress, as knowledge is lost forever with the lack of materials for printed media (and a lack of time in a subsistence farming settlement to write down, for example, a basic outline of electronics engineering).

This question may cover a lot of this. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/158429/if-120-experts-in-12-different-fields-were-sent-back-10-000-years-could-they-re/158467#158467

They would regress to pre-stone-age levels within a generation.

You may want to take a look at the Riverworld books

It depends on many factors including climate zone, significant predators, topology (fertile river plains / desert / high alpine year long snow / ...), access to resources (food, timber, metal ores, rivers (water power), ...), and much more, BUT ...
Contrary to much of what others say, if the terraformers intended you to survive well WITH technology, and instead you had all the knowledge but none of the equipment then in a moderately benign environment you could be in the 1600s- 1800s range in 100 years - with some elements of 20th century capability. (eg spark gap radio and maybe thermionic valves, internal and external combustion engines, ... maybe even flight)
If they can survive reasonably easily food and shelter wise, the main driver is group commitment, unity and continuity of vision. As they were selected to survive and prosper and to work together and to be committed then "only" the physical technology has been taken away, so then all you have is "a slow start".
If you can obtain eg copper and better again iron you are well on your way.
I'm a professional electrical engineer. IF I was free to pursue my craft (quite an if) and if copper was available (another big if) then I could give you crude spark gap radio communications in the 5 to 20 year window.
The delay is not the radio technology per se but the precursors. We'd need to develop power sources, wire (see Copper), insulation, ... .  Permanent magnets would be useful. You can have gunpowder or similar with no more than effort and commitment. Sulfur helps. Potassium Nitrate you get from urine processing and carbon is presumably readily obtained.
Somewhere in the same time span you may be able to have crude thermionic valves. Semiconductors are significantly more resource constrained and may "take a while". Magnetics depend on materials available.
Reading Jarred Diamond's "Guns Germs and Steel"  will give you an exceedingly good picture of how civilisation and capability (food, technology, literature, technology, firearms, domesticated animals, crops, ...) developed where it did, how it did and when it did (or a plausible explanation that may be wrong :-) ) and also why things did not happen differently.
If you are crafting a tale where you want significant results in 100 years you do not need magic, but you need some fortuitous happenstances that you make look as unremarkable as desired. If you look at the role that Hobbits played in the Lord of the Rings you find that they "just happened" to be capable of finding, using, travelling, creating, surviving, ... to an extent that strains normal suspension of disbelief. Part of Tolkiens magic lies in being able to make all they achieve seem plausible.
Go and do you likewise :-) .
As a start: You'd like to find animals which are about as capable, tameable, strong and useful as horses, something akin to sheep, dog equivalents and similar. Bees or similar will exist. You want a few core plants that are edible and useful and easy to grow and benign. Look into the Moringa tree - EVERY part is edible, the seeds can be cooked and then can be stored for months, you can eat the leaves off the tree.
The seed pods purify water (flocculants) ... It grows immensely fast - first crop in under a year. It can grow to well over 20 feet and is often trimmed to limit height for ease of cropping. Your terraformers decided it was a good idea to sow some. And, why not?
Your terraformers almost certainly established a number of crop species prior to your arrival. They also almost certainly chose hospitable resource rich climate zones. Too much of this is "cheating" BUT you can lean on the fact that this was planned and decide how much you use in your story.
Iron and copper ores are perhaps the most desirable technology drivers. Zinc is useful. Alumin(i)um has to wait as it is took energy intensive.  Limestone will give you concrete. (Flyash helps - be near an inactive volcano.
Once you have copper and magnetics wind turbines are relatively easy. Waterwheels can provide mechanical power - or electrical with Cu and magnetics.
Is it possible? - certainly.
MIGHT they all die? - certainly.
Might they all stumble along at a subsistence level? - probably not.
It's probably a case of death or glory.
If your founders wanted you to do well "with technology" much of the resource is there but harder to obtain.
Finally, read Kim Stanley Robinson's "Red/Green/Blue Mars" trilogy. They had mega technology, but much of his tales are still useful.

This was helpful, thank you. My main thing was that unlike the questions other people linked, I didn't need them to get to modern tech in a century, that would've been stupid. I just wanted a grasp of where they might be at. I'm probably going to substantially increase the population, probably at least several million across the planet in other underground bunkers. I'm probably going to place them at the early modern maybe, and up the timeline to 150 years.


How much technological progress could one expect them to make in a century?
That depends on what they know.
Do they know how to make stone, bone and wood tools? If yes, there is a chance that some of them will survive. If no, then they are all dead. Sad.
Do they know how to hunt animals with pointed sticks? If yes, there is a chance that some of them will survive. If no, then they are all dead. Sad.
Do they know how to tan animal hides with pre-historic technology? If yes, there is a chance that some of them will survive. If no, then they are all dead. Sad.
And so on. Long term survival in the wilderness is a highly specialized skill.
Assuming that maybe a thousand of them survive past the first year, they have a sporting chance of establishing a breeding population.
As for technological progress, forget it. For the first few centuries they will be too busy surviving.

How much could we expect their population to increase?
That depends on how many fertile women are among the thousand survivors, and on how optimistic the writer is. Personally, I would consider anything above 0.5% per year (meaning a doubling of the population every 150 years or so) to be excessively optimistic. In the real world, pre-historic populations doubled every 2,000 years or thereabouts.



Even people with the skills will have problems if they don't know the area. I have hunted in the past (including bow-hunting) and even did my own butchering, but I would have an incredibly difficult time if you were to give me a piece of rock and say "here, make a knife out of this then go carve up that animal", even if that rock were of an appropriate type for making knives. And as for making a hunting-quality bow from scratch? Forget about it. Don't even get started on recognizing human-edible plants of an unfamiliar biome.

It takes a lot of training and practice to be able to make a workable knife out of a good piece of flint.

This answer was provided to this version of the question.

This question is very similar to Speedrun to the moon in one lifetime? and my answer to that question is relevant here, but I'd like to change the focus.
Answer: Almost no advancement at all — from a certain point of view
2,500 people with all kinds of specialties wake up from suspended animation and find...
nothing....
They have their cryogenic equipment, perhaps the building it was in, a power generator as might be necessary for that equipment, some basic maintenance stuff probably left behind by the folks who built the installation, but that's it.
And four hours later they start getting hungry.
Those 2,500 people start doing the one and only thing they can do — and it has nothing to do with technological development. They start gathering food. Not hunting, they don't have time to make the tools they need to do that at first. Just gathering. Gathering food, water and fuel for fire.
And they do that over and over. But they're smart! They're efficient! So they figure out where to gather specific kinds of wild foods so they can free some people to start building tools for hunting. That makes them hunter-gatherers and it frees up a few more people.
Rain falls. It gets cold in the winter season (let's be really generous and say they don't experience snow in the first year or two). So people are struggling to build crude shelters and turn animal skins into clothes and blankets and to remove the remarkable amount of sewer and refuse created by 2,500 people...

And then the first injuries happen.
And then the first deaths happen.
And then the first babies are born.

It takes 12-16 years to raise a child to be a useful laborer in a society, so every person who's sick or dead or taking care of babies is a person NOT gathering food or hunting or building or otherwise providing for 2,500 people who get hungry every 4-8 hours and they will get hungry because they're not at desk jobs like they were expecting. They're burning 5,000-10,000 calories a day just to stay alive.
Excepting whatever few resources that can be stripped from wherever they were in cryo... the stone age is entered after 2-3 months

Stone age begins in 2-3 months.
The bronze age would likely be skipped. Having a lot of modern info in their heads they'd likely skip straight to the iron age.
Iron age begins at best in 2-4 years.

And there's a VERY IMPORTANT point to make here. Getting to the iron age requires one really important thing... iron. That's not as trite as it sounds. That means finding iron ore (explorers...) and setting up basic smelting and foundries and taking people away from food, which at this point would be basic agriculture, to mine the ore and run the smelters, etc. The funny thing about being educated in advanced specialties... none of those specifics might be in the inventory of your 2,500 people. That means they're rediscovering that tech. Easier, certainly, but it's still taking time and people, the two resources you DON'T have in abundance. As the author you could make the iron ore easily nearby and include someone who happens to know ancient smelting and foundry techniques.... But at that point this question should be closed as Too Story-Based. So... either you contrive to make all the tech you want happen in the 100 year time frame (VTC:Too Story-Based) or you live with the fact that for generations you won't see significant technological advancement.

Classical Era would probably be skipped in favor of moving quickly to charcoal and steel, allowing for sawmills.
Medieval era would begin in the 50-75 year range. You don't have anywhere near the people needed to create chemical factories so you can't get to kerosene, petroleum, etc. in this short period of time. Implementing technology (the info in people's heads) takes time and people: building buildings, moving resources like water and sewer, agriculture/mining/forestry, creating power (initially kinetic like water wheels, but eventually electricity). Etc.

There is no way on the face of the proverbial planet your 2,500 can get to the Early Modern Era (starting CE 1500) in just 100 years.
You might be able to get to muskets. Maybe. But you'd have to write your story to make it happen. Otherwise, after 100 years you people will have swords and a lot of them will be dedicated to educating the ever increasing number of children and writing books. Lots and lots of books. Over and over because while it wouldn't take long to get to moveable type it will take a while to get to indelible ink.
If you didn't read my answer to that earlier question until now, go read it now. It covers this issue from a different angle. You might also want to look at...

This answer
This answer
This answer


I was actually thinking of your answer when I read this question.

Iron ore is actually very easy.  Useful amounts of iron can be extracted from just about any environment which is a big part of why it replaced bronze.  No, you may not have 70% iron ore conveniently underfoot, but any random rock you pick up has an average content of 5% iron and most people live within walking distance of a 10-30% iron deposit.  It takes more than one smelt to purify random rocks into useful iron, but as long as you know how to make a kiln hot enough, you can make iron tools just about anywhere on Earth.  They are just more expensive without a good ore source.

"Lots and lots of books. Over and over" <- this is easily solved with clay tablets or etched stone. They are not as space efficient as books, but they last a lot longer.

It also takes much, much longer to quarry the stone or produce the tablets, etch the stone or fire the tablets, than it does to write things down with ink.

@Nosajimiki Everything you've said is a good point! But nothing you've said "easily solves" anything. Every person pulled away from survival jeapardizes the whole. That's a critical point in my answer. 5% iron isn't a godsend. It's a nightmare for the time it takes to dig up (vs. 70%) 14X more ore and remove that much more tailings and slag. Ugh.

The question has been updated to provide for a large-but-finite stockpile of food, medicine, and also included some wilderness survival experts.  That would give them several months in which most people could be focused on infrastructure while a dedicated few work out how/what/where to hunt.  How would that affect this answer?  Would it just mean that they could be at the iron age level by the time the stockpile runs out, or is there still too much that has to be reinvented?

@JBH 5% is just an average.  In my own back yard if I dig down just a couple of feet, there are layers of clay with very little iron an other layers that are very red indicating 10-12%.  This clay can be further sluiced to a concentration of about 30% iron with very little effort compared to smelting.   So, even using the resources that are literally underfoot, I could produce bloomery iron that is only about 2-3 times as expensive as if I had locally sourced hematite or bog iron.  Since forging remains the same, the final cost of a tool is only about 25-75% higher depending on what I need.

this is why Japan was able to have a thriving steel industry despite a total lack of iron ore.

@jdunlop No, clay tablets are WAY easier to make in a primitive setting than paper and ink.  When I made my cat's grave stone, it only took  me a few minutes to dig up the clay and make a tablet out of it.  The only time consuming part was making the kiln and firing it, but a primitive society will already have and operate these for making jugs, pots, dishes, bricks, and tiles.  Fitting thin clay tablets into any spare spaces you have is easy making it a practically free step.  Paper and ink making however requires more specialized equipment and a lot more manual steps.

@Nosajimiki Japan had a thriving steel industry despite a total lack of iron ore because of international trade. The question isn't tagged [tag:magic].

@Bobson The OP might get their hand slapped. Changing questions in a way that invalidates existing answers is a no-no on this site.

Interest only. Japanese steel making from 5th century AD . Korean technology. Iron sands useful.  https://www.aichi-steel.co.jp/ENGLISH/smart/mi/columns/03.html#:~:text=The%20history%20and%20social%20significance,around%20the%20fifth%20century%20AD.

In space, there are never too many redundancies
If the space program in question is run by sensible engineers, they will have a chain of redundancy for everything their mission requires for success.  So, if the plan is to land on the planet and use industrial grade matter replicators to create a new city, that is just Plan A.  Space travel has way too many variables for Plan A to be the only plan.  They will have a Plan B, C, D, and E that the crew has been properly equipped and trained to carry out.  So, when their industrial matter replicators don't work, they will bring out their smaller auxiliary replicator, also known as Plan B... but Opps, the problem is not the replicators, it's that the reactor was damaged mid-journey; so, they have no power.  No worries, time for Plan C: their ship also has auxiliary batteries which will be enough to manufacture some minimal infrastructure... only that's been depleted because the reactor was damaged so early on in the journey.  Okay, Plan D: is to burn the remaining rocket fuel in the lander to run a generator to make some really basic infrastructure.  It will be spartan, but it will do... except that the generator has a big crack in it... what terrible luck, but even this is not an unforeseen mission outcome.  On to Plan E: use only the local resources to survive.
While this may sound like a hopeless scenario for a crew that was expecting to land in the lap of luxury, there is no way such a large crew would be sent without survival experts.

Thus, while they have many specialists in many fields, preselected for their expertise, they are on their own.

Astronauts are not just recruited.  They go through years of training and preparation to make sure that they know all of their redundancy plans are are skilled enough to implement them.  So, since Plan E was always a known possibility; basic survival training would be a part of every colonist's training process.  Doctors would know how to fashion a splint from found objects.  Construction workers would be trained in mortise and tenon construction.  Metallurgist would know how to build and operate a bloomery kiln.  Mechanics would know how to knap stone tools. Biologists would know how to farm and forage. Polymer Chemists would know how to weave natural fibers into cloth.  With every crewmate working together, they will likely face a very hard first year or two, but within 3-5 years they could have a fully functional settlement of approximately medieval technology, and by 10 years, they will likely have a lot of proto-industrial machines much like you saw in ancient Rome and Egypt like water powered sawmills and bow lathes.
Limitations of a small population
However, this is where their tech will plateau. Anything more advanced than proto-industrial machines requires a much larger population than 2500 people.  A full industrial revolution only works when economy of scale allows it, which will not happen until your population reaches at least a few million people.
Because your population will all operate under the authority of your mission control's government, and because your crew was medically screened before being put on the ship, your people will be able to reproduce much faster than their tech level suggests because there will be no wars or communicable diseases to worry about, and famines will happen a bit, but in all likelihood, only the most habitable and stable part of the planet will be chosen for the first colony; so, even this should be of a minor concern once you get a year or two in.  These factors together mean your rate of growth could be as high as 500-1000% in the first century which is much faster than the actual medieval period saw.  But, even by this optimistic estimation, we are looking at a maximum population of 7500-15,000 colonists.  This is still way too small to advance to any widespread use of industrialization. If anything, you will see a gradual decline in technology as the first generation of highly trained an diversely educated colonists will have died off and been replaced by a more practical minded new generation of colonists whose main focus will not be to maintain that which was, but to do what makes the most since for what now is.
So when those fancy machines designed by the first crew break down, and as they run out of parts from the original ship to salvage for advanced materials, they may see their tech slowly backslide as they fall into a sort of dark age. Sure the old machinist's great grandson may have been taught how to make lathes, pottery wheels, and windmills, but perhaps he never bothered to learn how to do trigonometry; so, his machines are a little worse for not knowing how to make them as precisely.  And yes, the old biologists great grandson may be a perfectly able bodied farmer, but N-P-K ratios and micronutrients never quite made since to him; so, he just goes through the ritual of crop rotations without understanding the little adjustments needed to maintain optimal fertility, but because there are so few people to fill each required role, it creates a lot of opportunities for the importance of certain pieces of knowledge to be forgotten.
Forgotten Knowledge is not lost
That said, just because the newest generation may not be the students of science that their parents were, that does not mean that knowledge is lost, just forgotten.  It is likely that the crew of this mission was never intended to remember every single scientific fact and survival skill.  Just like everything else, the ship records needed for the preservation of key knowledge will also have reducnences.  Archival quality textbooks made with water resistant inks and linen paper will likely accompany the crew as a backup for the electronic records.  The landing ship's library may be this civilization's most sacred resource.  In it will be all the plans they need to make their stone and iron-aged tools and machines, instructions for how to identify and use local flora and fauna, etc. And even the a lot of the more advanced stuff that they may not have much use for just yet like quantum physics, general relativity, and computer science.
As long as the library survives (accidental and purposeful burning is a very real possibility over long time periods), they will also have everything they need for each generation to have a Renaissance where growing populations and increasing free time will allow them to try out new things from the old books.  By 100 years, they may start to build a lot of one-off versions of the machines that made the industrial revolution.  There might be a one or two powered looms, a single large blast furnace for making cheap steel, a couple of biodiesel or alcohol powered hand-build tractors, etc.  Final products will still have to be artisan works due to low demands, but the resources they need in bulk will likely be mechanized by this point.

this is an excellent answer, though I think you forgot to focus on one trick that helps battle the loss of knowledge: writing. the making of clay tablets, wax tablets, and finally crude, medieval-style paper and parchment is withing their capabilities, which means at least some of the knowledge could be preserved, even as the people who knew it died of old age. There would be a decline, but not as steep.

@GoingDurden That is a good point: and not just primitive records either.  The rule of redundancy that my whole answer is based on means that they should already have plenty of written information outside of their electronic records. I've updated my answer accordingly.

This guy has reached the late stone age with some years of work.
His notable failures:

He could make coke, but his iron results were simply futile, even in the tremendous invested energy and time
He did not even try to create copper or bronze
He did not create any large building (possible in the lack of need)
Also nothing large stones

Note that his entire technolgy is focusing on the combination of various stone age-level solutions, he is doing them quite professionally.
Note that having well available land area, they can live probably a good life in the stone age customs. If they are many, they organize well both the research/development and engineering/manufacturing, and they do not forget, how the technology works, I believe they can be fine for a steam age yet in the life of their first generation.
Things are becoming hard at that point. Not only science is exploding at that point, also engineering does it. You won't have enough minds. They will need population.
Note, having population in that environment means that you need to have sex with people don't always like, due to the small count of availability. Males can live with it, but a women socialized in the current western society, probably not. Pregnancy will be also life threatening, and a large part of the newly born children will unavoidably die. It won't be an adventure film, it will be your own dead child. Odds are that mental problems would be a lead cause of death (suicide or murder), and the second or third generation survivors will focus probably those and not to the forgetting holy scriptures of the ancients
But I think, if the social structure remains stable, they have a chance that once a newly built spaceship will come back.

It's important to remember that Primitive technology, while a great channel, he has a lot of constraints. He has limited land to work on, he is not able to hunt animals due to local laws - in a situation where you have a ton of people in a world vacant of other people, you could certainly find better sources of iron than the iron bacteria that he has to settle for.

@WasatchWind Yes, but out of the camera, he likely has at least good car and a good home, from the tremendous youtube income today :-) Note that youtube pays about 1 cent / visit. I think, what we could measure, that is the time what the creator could invest into his technology. If there are, for example, 100 well educated, highly motivated and idealist humans...

That definitely helps his channel that he doesn't have to worry about taking care of himself. He does however suffer from lack of raw materials and more people to work with him.

@GraySheep youtube does not pay 1 cent per view, as that would be a RPM of $10.00 which insane. it's estimated RPM in primitive technology's category is about $3.50, and could be lower or higher but not anywhere close to 10. also what counts as a view is not as straightforwards as "a visit" but that's neither here nor there. of course, he's still making a lot of money.

@Themoonisacheese Thanks - I had not so exact numbers until now :-) But the important thing is that the creator probably can create such videos as his daily job (might oe might not do that), which might be important to estimate the time need of the reachable technological development from absolute zero into the late stone age.

Almost everything here depends on details. What exact skills? What resources are present on the planet? What tools or equipment from the space ship are useable?
So I'm making a lot of assumptions:

They have a wide array of well-selected skills and all of them are good at their professions
The planet is essentially Earth when it comes to available resources such as metal, water, wood, etc.
Low-tech materials and tools are available. Nothing that requires electronics to work, but hammers, axes, shovels, etc. as well as rope, fabric, metal or wooden poles and beams, etc.
Colony-starting goods such as seeds are available.

Starting Out
The survival experts will do the right things, so when the rest of the crew wake up, they have basic shelters and the immediate area has been scouted for freshwater sources and available food. Hunting tools like simple spears and even some traps can be made in a few hours if you have some rope and stuff like knives or axes available. I assume in #3 above that these are available.
Now here's your main hindrance: You can't sustain 2500 people in one place on hunting and gathering. We know that because no hunter and gatherer tribes are anywhere near that size. You say they have food for about a year. That means they need to start agriculture pretty much immediately to get at least one harvest. Fortunately, we have assumption 4.
The first few years will be tough and they will focus mostly on survival. But with our assumptions above, they would be in essentially the situation that early european settlers were in America. You've got a bunch of stuff to get started, now you're on your own.
Let's assume that in the one year before their supplies run out they manage to set up a self-sufficient town. That's a big if, but with the assumptions I made it's doable.
Progress
Now into advancing technologically. Almost all of human technology is built upon previous technology. Sometimes just the idea, but more often than not the outcome. For high-tech machinery you need precision manufacturing that requires advanced metal-working technology that is only possible if you have the necessary smelting techniques and tools, which you can only get with simpler metalworking, for which you need coal first to get fires hot enough to melt metal, and so on.
A lot of human history is trial-and-error, and our settlers could bypass a lot of the errors. However, a lot of especially crafting is in experience and learning-by-doing. Even if you know all the chemical formulas and academic details, you can't go from nothing to ball bearings and forklifts. It takes a lot of practice to get things just right.
These modern people have modern experiences. They will struggle with ancient and medieval technology, even if they understand all the details. Pretty much all of us here could explain how a medieval catapult works, but building one would still be challenging project and it would most likely take a couple iterations before we're anywhere even near the actual historical ones.
Each of these steps can take years. Sure, you know the melting point of iron and the mixture of bronze and zinc and all that. But how, exactly, do you get a charcoal fire to that temperature? This will take quite a bit of trial-and-error, even if the expertise of our settlers speeds things up.
Same with steam engines, which is probably the first automation that you'd go for. They are relatively easy and you can increase their power output as your materials get better. But do you know what early steam engines were famous for? Blowing up. There would almost certainly be a number of accidents before our settlers have the details figured out, because these details are largely lost to history - we don't need that particular knowledge anymore, so no profession is trained in the fine construction details that make the difference between a locomotive and an explosion.
Scaling Up
The next thing to consider is that scaling something up is an entirely different thing from inventing it. The way from a prototype engine, machine or other device to a mass-produced, affordable and reliable one can be longer than the invention itself. Sometimes, you need to establish entire supply chains, resource production and must invent new machines to manufacture the thing.
The first predecessors of automobiles appeared in the 17th century. The first steam-powered car was built in the 18th century. The first prototype with an internal combustion engine was made in the 19th century. And yet, as we all know, it wasn't until the beginning of the 20th century that automobiles started to be more than a curiosity.
Other Things To Consider
Finally, we can't assume that technological progress would be all that our 2500 people do. There are all other kinds of things to spend time on. There will be politics required to start a town, with administrative tasks, political factions, judges and lawyers. Someone needs to take out the trash. Humans want art and entertainment.
Which is to say that only a fraction of our available workforce will at any given time contribute to progress.
Passing It On
Even if all that runs very well, we start with 2500 adults. Which means that at the end of our century, none of them will still be alive. In addition to making progress, they also need to teach the next generation everything they know. Which in many professions is really hard if the technology you're teaching isn't available. Imagine a computer science course when there are no computers to write and test your software, for example.
So a lot of knowledge will be lost as the adults we started with get older and die off. The generation at the end of our century will not at all be similar to the generation we started with.
Conclusion
It might seem like having all these experts to start with would give you a fast track in technological progress. And sure, it does. But the fast track still contains a lot of experimentation, setbacks and building blocks that are needed for other building blocks.
Starting as we assumed, a hundred years isn't all that much time. Unlike human history, they can't build on existing trade networks, resources, institutions, economic systems and previous generation technology.
Given all that, we can only guess. But I would be surprised if in a century, even with all that's given and the assumption I made, they would make it into a steampunk era. There is too much fiddling with details, too much specific know-how that is lost to the modern world. A large amount of technological knowledge will simply not be able to be put into practical application for lack of tools, materials, manufacturing, etc.
Story Impact
If your story needs them to reach a specific level of technology, supply enough of the predecessor technology to build on. It's not a stretch to assume that a colony ship would contain some simple (rugged and easy to maintain without access to high-tech equipment) generators. Those could then easily be repurposed as engines. Or that a colony ship would bring some manufacturing equipment for the settlers to use. Again, them being able to repair them on their own would force these to be mostly mechanical and simple.
Having even a couple generators for power, presses and drills and other stuff available can dramatically accelerate the process and allow them to simply bypass entire generations of technology.

Depends where they were and what they had with them and the dangers they face.
Tropical Islands had 10 to fifteen or more children quite often. Life was easy. The sea is easy to harvest from and they had root crops and coconuts. So lots of leisure time and settlements. If specialists had the ambition to create they'd have the time to work it out rather than spend all their time grubbing around for food and moving around.
If they were reduced to hunter gathering it's a different story, they still have leisure time, but they can't settle for long and because they move, they can't have as many kids.
If they had seed for crops and it wasn't dangerous, they could farm and expand rapidly. Search for resources and specialists could make a start at making the tools to make the tools.
Wilderness survival is difficult if you're on your own and food is scarce, but some places food isn't a problem and having a large group is an asset.
The Māori populated the whole of New Zealand within 300 years starting with just a few canoe loads and were busy waging war over territory when Europeans first showed up. Despite moving to a temperate country from the tropics and any root crops they brought with them not being compatible. Birth rates are very high when societies prioritise it and can feed their kids. We have families here in Polynesia with 15-17 children. I have 6 and it's not extraordinary.

And of course birth rate is often influenced by religion too, I speak from experience as the middle of five kids, which isn't too uncommon here in Utah.  : )

@WasatchWind yeah, if life is good and society values child rearing, populations can easily double every few years

There are three significant variables: exactly which technologies are known, the number of people sent (Manpower) and natural resource availability.
The most important step would probably be recording existing knowledge (An iterative process that could take decades), so without a way to make decent paper from native vegetation you'd be in trouble.
Just the knowledge that something can be done will speed things up immensely. With the right resources available, you could probably begin working with small amounts of iron in a few weeks--almost no need to go through the stone age.
If you could record knowledge and had enough people, you'd probably end up with a agricultural/scientific society--spend your manpower on food, minimal housing and research, don't loose focus building pyramids, cities and castles, just what you need to survive, create a library and build on what you've figured out.
Once you had decent supply of metals (which really don't require any difficult tech, just manpower and some metal ratios that someone will certainly know) I'd think electric power would be right behind.  From there you'd get to 1950's electric tech in a few years, and even transistors maybe.  Going beyond starts to take more precise equipment and some iterations of large-scale more precise tooling--so again, lots of manpower required.
If your person count is like 12, it's going to be longer for everything.  If it's in the hundreds with everyone able to work towards a common goal you could be talking less than a decade to get the first car running.  A couple more decades for usable (but primitive) computer.

Most answers focus on development like our society and making assumptions that are not optimal. For instance, copper and bronze should not be skipped because there will be easy accessible surface copper. Assuming they have every engineering book in their digital library, it will not take too long before they can create steam engines. However, finding and processing iron will take longer due to lack of enough prospectors and miners.
Creating cement is not that difficult, you could setup a system within weeks, but carrying concrete mixture to create buildings would be an issue. This might lead to interesting buildings with flat concrete bottom with log walls. Another example would be transportation. From steam engine, they might quickly build cars, but lack of roads will be an issue. The list goes on like this.
Their level of technology will be all over the place. You might be able to see advancements as far as 20th century within a decade or so but the people could very well be at stone age level for some technologies even after a few generations.
How quickly they find what they need will dictate where they would be in 100 years but their technological level will definitely be odd.

Very dependent on how you want to tell your story with potential struggles they may have with flora and fauna and especially if they are able to access the storage of tools that are locked away (which can be a question of, how long before they can make thermite, and the answer to that might be fairly quickly), but I think without those tools that within 100 years they could potentially even reach technology levels of early 1700s depending on availability of resources.
Now early struggles are shelter, food and water, but you say they have rations for a year, which seems to be plenty of time to search for flora to gather and farm and fauna to exploit.
Now you don't have specialists in everything, you are starting your toolmaking from scratch and it's unlikely you have some ancient anthropologist specialist aware of neolithic toolmaking. But useful tools are fairly basic, it doesn't need an expert to make a sharp stone hatchet to cut trees. It's fairly basic knowledge on how to make fires, and for much of early human life the struggles for metallagury was not what ores to smelt and how to work it, but making fire hotter, and for making fire hotter it's getting more oxygen, and people can be aware of how to make effective bellows. More people should be aware of tools but they will have to make more simple versions until they keep refining processes to make better tools.
When you are rediscovering technology you don't have the same struggles which comes with human development, many discoveries are not due to theoretical understanding of issues and applying them, but pure luck. That doesn't apply for your protagonists as they  already know the discoveries and it's just trial and error on how to make them.
As the author you can decide how much struggle they have, and the big struggle that can be hard to really protect against is environmental. It's going to be hard to survive an ice age, or suffer from extreme floods, blazing heatwaves etc..., but hostile fauna, even megafauna akin to dinosaurs are probably not going to be a great challenge. The pointy stick has been a staple and consistent partner in human warfare over millenia. Granted you may need a really big pointy stick to deal with something like a T-Rex, and probably traps involving many big pointy sticks.
If you are being a kind author and reliable sources of resources are nearby without much dangers then basic survival needs can be met easily, and experts working together will be able to rapidly progress.
If you are being a mean author and resources are scare, then it can take far longer to develop. as much of struggle will just be finding resources.
You have a large range to choose from, but I think that it would be possible that with 200 years in your story you could even reach modern day technologies.

Yeah, the main thing I need for my plot is some amount of suffering, but some decent progress. I decided that they have far more people put to sleep in the bunkers, at least a million across the planet - and when they get out they have heavy competition for resources.
So the commander wakes up 150 years late, and he finds his descendants chomping at the bit to get access to his keycard to open the heavy equipment and advanced supplies cache - which he has reservations about.
He then finds that they need to depart the planet, needs to convince them to leave, that sort of thing.

I don't think you would be able to have a cache that wouldn't be able to be broken into within a few months, let alone hundreds of years though. Thermite isn't hard to make, even without thermite just mining away at walls can get through. There is no lock, safe or fortification which is safe from someone determined enough to get in. Fort Knox is safe because of the thousands of soldiers defending it, not it's thick walls or mult-layered safe access. You could have turrets or something but people will figure out a way. A hidden cache seems convulted for terraforming project.
