# Are there any planets that are similar to Earth but with high amounts of metal discovered yet?

Tags: planets, species, telepathy

I have a species that I am currently creating that uses telepathy. They would need high amounts of metal in their habitat to be able to communicate the way they do. Humans would also need to visit this planet for an extended amount of time. The planet would need a similar atmosphere to Earth's and it would need water, other life forms, and an earth like crust. So if anyone knows of any planets similar to my needs please tell me, I'm flexible so they don't have to completely match my description.

Comment: Please look at this post https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/93856/physics-of-a-metal-poor-world please define what you would consider high amounts of metal, obviously if the crust is metal plants aren't going to grow there.

Comment: Are you sure you need more metal on the whole world? There are a number so species that live in limited areas because of local concentrations of something. We move the resources we want all over the world.

Comment: Yes clarification would help, Earth is an extremely metal rich planet, ~50% by mass.

Comment: Earth has lots of metal and is the most metal world we know of.

Comment: Once the James Webb telescope is launched it should be able to directly view the atmosphere composition's of the exoplanets that have so far been discovered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the data from Keplar are pretty freely available, do some homework and come back.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Madison. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is ready and willing to help with trouble you are having while developing your world, but we strongly encourage users to conduct their own research prior to asking the community for help. That being said, is there any particular reason you need to use a previously discovered planet? Since this is worldbuilding, feel free to build a world of your own. Feel free to take the [tour] to get a better understanding of the site.

Comment: @Ash Lack of research is a reason to downvote, not close. The fact that there are more than a few planets to choose from makes this question too broad, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find evidence of the discovery of a metal-heavy exoworld.  This doesn't mean there isn't one, ony that I couldn't find one.

Please note that humanity is in its most infant stages of exoplanetary discovery.  We get whomping excited whenever we discover *one.*  We're beginning to have some success analyzing atmospheres and are looking for solutions to discover plant life (which, if you think about it, is far more important to humans than the discovery of metals).

> Nearly all the exoplanets that we've found are giant planets.  Giant planets have one giant problem: high gravity.  Nevertheless, I instantly fell in love with GJ1214b while searching for your answer.  It is a planet 2.5X bigger than earth that orbits its star in (wait for it...) every 1.6 *days.*  (That's our days....)  ***Please keep your arms and legs inside the ride at all times!***  However, the most recent analysis was about its atmosphere. (Which, curiously, they consider "metal rich" because it has H<sub>2</sub>O.  I'm not a chemist, so I don't understand the reference, but good on it!)

However, after my admittedly brief foray into the Internet, I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that there won't be a difinitive answer to your question.  However, *that's a blessing.*

With public knowledge of a planet's metal makeup would come other publically available information about that planet which is more than likely to make it utterly uninhabitable.  In other words, the data you want to make your story "real" would actually kill your story.

> Solution: *pick one.*  It's what authors have been doing for centuries.  The less the public knows about it the better.  Heck, choose GJ1214b!  With a "year" of 1.6 sol days it would make for some interesting stories.  Or invent a planet surrounding a known G-class star.  The fact that we can't detect them (yet) is actually a benefit to you.  It sets you free to create your world.

And to lend credence to my suggestion: Issac Asimov's popular *Foundation* series of books were primarily based on the imaginary planet [Terminus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminus_(planet)), which is metal poor (a key plot point).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are inventing telepaths, I take away you are not constrained by what has actually been discovered - you do not need to have an actual exoplanet for this work of fiction.

Earth is similar to what you need.  Since you are making it up you can make it up to be like Earth.  You would not be the first world builder to go this route.  It saves a lot of time as an author (even more time if you are doing a science fiction show on a budget) because you can point out the differences - for example the (comparatively) large amounts of copper in the crust, or the larger nickel-iron core, or the frequent occurrence of manganese nodules from an ancient ocean, or the fact that the birds are very mean and will peck your head in a second.  Then the rest can be imagined by your reader as more or less like Earth, until you point out some other difference that moves your story along or is good local color.