# How many people does it take to run a self sufficient colony

Tags: space-colonization, population

How many people would it take to to run a self sufficient colony? I'd say it would  take from 20-1,000,000 to live comfortably and still be a colony. But I want to know if it's possible with less than ten. Also, famous engineer and inventor Elon Musk says it's nearly impossible with less than a million people including  children.

Comment: This question and its answers need to be merged with the [2014 Question that is is a duplicate of](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3/what-is-the-minimum-human-population-necessary-for-a-sustainable-colony). It certainly doesn't need to be reopened, as it's not asking anything new and hasn't been edited for improvement or differentiation!